# How do I add another gmail account to an existing user

Tags: django-authentication, django-allauth

From my frontend, I can use `django-allauth` to authenticate a new Google user with the following endpoint:

`myapp.com/auth/google/`

I would instead like it to authorize the account for an existing user, enabling the user to access multiple gmail accounts from my application. I presume it's possible because it seems like the models are set up to accommodate this. However, I can't find any documentation for adding a second account to an existing user through allauth's api.